# ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.8

Getting error for this cell

```py
x=(x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3)
wine.feature_names

f1='hue'
f2='proline'
basex=np.array(xtrain[[f1,f2]])
basey=np.array(ytrain)
xtest=np.array(xtest[[f1,f2]])
ytest=np.array(ytest)

x=pd.DataFrame(basex)
y=basey
plt.scatter(x.iloc[:,0],x.iloc[:,1],c=y,s=15)
plt.scatter(0.25,0.2,c=x,marker='x',s=100)
```

What's the issue?

Comment: One issue is that you didn't show what `basex` contains. Another is that you didn't show `basey`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell updated it!